# jquery inserted HTML is rendered as a raw text

Tags: jquery

I have weird situation, I have that string

```
lorem&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;ipsum&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;a&lt;br/&gt;b&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;c
```

which is put into a div:

```
$('div.desc').html(that_string);
```

or

```
$('div.desc').html($.parseHTML(that_string));
```

but in both cases it is being rendered as a raw text:

```
lorem<br/><br/>ipsum<br/><br/>a<br/>b<br/><br/>c
```

instead of

```
lorem

ipsum

a
b

c
```

Why ?

Comment: Thats string is HTML encoded. You'll have to HTML decode it, before it can be parsed in as HTML.

Comment: If you are getting this from a div and not from a custom made variable you have to do

$('div.desc').html($('#element').html());

You get a decoded HTML element

Comment: Try Underscore's `unescape()` function - http://underscorejs.org/#unescape

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('div.desc').html(decodeURI(that_string));
//OR
$('div.desc').html($.parseHTML(decodeURI(that_string)));
```

The `decodeURI()` function will decode the string so it will output `<`, `>` etc.

Answer (score 20):

You can just trick it with a little jQuery parsing

```
$('div.desc').html( $('<div />').html(that_string).text() );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggT5J/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with jQuery where raw HTML was being rendered as text. I fixed it by doing the following:

Target: `var txt = <h3> Hello <b>World</b><h3>`

`$(#class).text(txt)` to

`$(#class).html(txt)`

Now the content is being displayed on the website as HTML.