# jquery .html feature stripping tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm attempting to modify  elements and give them  elements. The Table and  elements are all created. However, upon attempting to load the s into the  the response text strips the s. I've verified response text is propping by loading it on it's own page, however when using the below code. The  tags get stripped.

```
$("#Records").load("get.php?"+str, function(){
    $('.trclass').each(function(){
        var id=this.id;
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                $('#'+id).html(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?Read=true&"+str2,false);
        xmlhttp.send();                      
    });
});
```

I've verified the responseText is correct. I'm fine with turning this into a .append() or a .load() just need something that works. I've seen solutions involving making a new div and putting a table in that and sending that back but that's way too hacky and I don't want to do that on get.php. Looking for a good solution. Hopefully from this section of code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry @Steve, fixed.

Comment: `var id=$(this)[0].id;` please please please just use `this.id`

Comment: _“I've verified the responseText is correct”_ – doesn’t sound like it; especially when what you posted as an answer gives you the expected result – that makes it likely that your `get.php` is not actually returning HTML code to make up elements in the first place, but has all HTML special characters _needlessly_ written as their entity counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here [jquery inserted HTML is rendered as a raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267775/jquery-inserted-html-is-rendered-as-a-raw-text)

I used the answer of $('div.desc').html($.parseHTML(unescape(that_string)));

And it worked perfectly.