# HTML-Code from JSON-File not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a backend system which saves HTML-Coder form the TInyMCE Editor to a DB.
Using a php file I access the db and convert the data to json which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the html-code is encoded. Aftwerwards I decode this JSON-Code and apply it to a div-container using jQuery:

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(data[i].Inhalt).text();
$(".mainText").html(decoded);
```

However it looks like this: [image]

What am I missing out? The HTML Code is not applied.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267775/jquery-inserted-html-is-rendered-as-a-raw-text).

Comment: @impinball not really. the reason is the text() method. it escapes characters so they never render in a browser.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Okay. You do have a point. I will hold the two as very similar to each other, and I do suspect, though, the same solution would work for this problem, as they both deal with unescaping HTML to display in its raw form.

Comment: Does this work if you change to this:  `$("<div/>").html(data[i].Inhalt);` for that first line?